# Splitting large drawable into small bitmaps

Tags: android

I have a large image file. I cannot load it into memory because it's too big. What I want to do is to grab part of the drawable resource on decode and store that into a smaller square bitmap which I can then use in my GLSurfaceview. I would be rendering multiple small squares each with their own texture cutout from the drawable. How can I go about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object

Comment: did you even read my question? I don't want a subsampled lower res image. I want multiple crop outs of the drawable.